# Why is my variable still nil after assignment via API request?

Tags: ios, swift, api

I am trying to build an app to track packages. Initially, the "delivered" property of the package  object is nil because we haven't gotten the data from the API yet. However, after the retrieving and assigning the value within the API call, I am still getting nil.

```
class Item: NSObject {
    var name: String?
    var carrier: String?
    var tracking: String?
    var delivered: Bool?
    var daysLeft: String?
    var date: String?
    init (name: String, carrier: String, tracking: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.carrier = carrier
        self.tracking = tracking
    }
}

func enterPackage (carrier: String, tracking: String) {
    var newItem = Item(name: "some name", carrier: carrier, tracking: tracking)
    print(newItem.delivered) //I am getting nil here, as expected because I haven't set it yet 
    self.loadItem(item: item)
    print(newItem.delivered) //Why am I still getting nil here and how do I fix this?
}

func loadItem(item: Item) {
    //Perform API request with item carrier and tracking data 
    //Purposely commented out private API information 

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        if let safeData = data {
            //Parse JSON and assign values to item
            self.parseJSON(data: safeData, item: item)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

func parseJSON(data: Data, item: Item) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder() 
    do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(ItemData.self, from: data)
        //Results are valid and here is the value assignment 
        item.delivered = decodedData.status_code == "DE" ? true : false 
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Here is the JSON file from the API request.

```
{
  "tracking_number": "182736488333",
  "status_code": "AC",
  "status_description": "Accepted",
  "carrier_status_code": "OC",
  "carrier_status_description": "Shipment information sent to FedEx",
  "ship_date": null,
  "estimated_delivery_date": "2020-05-04T07:00:00Z",
  "actual_delivery_date": null,
  "exception_description": null,
  "events": [
    {
      "occurred_at": "2020-04-28T07:52:00Z",
      "carrier_occurred_at": "2020-04-28T07:52:00-07:00",
      "description": "Shipment information sent to FedEx",
      "city_locality": null,
      "state_province": null,
      "postal_code": "925183100",
      "country_code": "US",
      "company_name": null,
      "signer": null,
      "event_code": "OC",
      "latitude": null,
      "longitude": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It would help if you display the json you receive from the service

Comment: @btogkas sure, I'll add it right now

Answer (score 2):

With reference to this code:

```
print(newItem.delivered) //I am getting nil here, as expected because I haven't set it yet 
self.loadItem(item: item)
print(newItem.delivered) //Why am I still getting nil here and how do I fix this?
```

You say:

> after the retrieving and assigning the value within the API call

But actually *both* lines `print(newItem.delivered)` happen *before* the API call. The API call is *asynchronous*.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are printing in the right thread since it is asynchronous or runs in background thread.

Try `print(newItem.delivered)` after the code `item.delivered = decodedData.status_code == "DE" ? true : false` in parseJSON function.

You can also create breakpoints in parseJSON function code to make sure the code has already been executed.